# How to avoid hard coding the website root in php to include the "config file"?

Tags: php, include, absolute-path

I want to know how can include code (config file)in php files that exist in different directory depths without using relative paths or direct absolute paths (hard coded paths).
I didn't like using the following:

- ../config.php
- ../../config.php
- ../../../config.php
- c:/wamp/www/mysite/config.php

The idea is to avoid having to modify multiples files when:

- The file is moved to other directory
- The root of the application is changed

What i have done is putting in my config file the following:

```
define("ROOT", dirname(__FILE__));
```

And in the other files:

```
$root = realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);
include $root ."/mysite/config.php";
```

You could see that I hard coded the folder of my site **"/mysite"**.
Can avoid hard coding this directory name?

Comment: There comes a point where you need to decide "how much information do I have to give my program to find the right file". If you move the file around, but it always has the same name, I suppose you could "search the entire tree for the information". But _somewhere_ you need to put a stake in the ground. I wonder if you are not distracting yourself with this...

Comment: `dirname(__FILE__)` can be replaced with `__DIR__` if you're on PHP 5.3 or higher (which you should be).

Comment: Hi @Floris, I come from ASP.NET where every file has direct access to the config file (web.config), so including files in the way that php works is new to me. That's the reason that I'm asking. You could see it as what is the best way to put the stake.

Answer (score 0):

Could you just change it to that?

```
$root = realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]) . "/mysite/";
include $root ."config.php";
```